# I cannot figure out the syntax to view specific instances of this dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, syntax

I am trying an exercise where I'm merging and pulling values from a dataframe for a specific case.

The code I have:

```
merge101 = pd.merge(orderdetails_df, orders_df, on = 'ordernumber')
merge102 = pd.merge(products_df, merge101, on = 'productcode')
```

One of the columns in merge102 is status. I am trying to select all rows that have status = 'On Hold'.

The code I have tried:

```
merge102[merge102$status == 'On Hold']
```

This produces a syntax error. Anyone have any idea how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference the `status` column in your dataframe in that manner, the syntax is `merge102[merge102.status == 'On Hold']`

You can also use `merge102[merge102['status'] == 'On Hold']`

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. Would you perhaps know how to use this code, while also selecting specific columns to be in the output (excluding the others)? Such as products code, status, and quantity?

Comment: Sure. The easiest way would be to make a new reference selecting only the columns you want, like:
`df2 = merge102[['code','status','quantity']]`
and then searching for the rows you want. Trying to do it all in one line would get a bit messy.

As an aside, if an answer works for your question, its really appreciated if you mark that answer as accepted to close the question :)

Comment: Thank you! How do I mark the question as answered? I've started a Master of Data Science and am brand new to the coding world!

Comment: On the answer you wish to mark as the accepted answer, click on the grey check mark beside it to set it to green. Only one answer may be the accepted answer, but you can change it at any time.